# Cleaning an output directory of pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, latexmk

I'm wondering how to achieve the following goal:

Suppose we have two directories, `src` and `out` in our project directory. Inside the first one there are my `.tex` files, which I compile with the following command:

```
pdflatex -output-directory=../out myfile.tex
```

Then, the `aux, log, toc, pdf` files appear iny the `out` directory. How can I clean up after compiling? The following:

```
cd out
latexmk -C
```

doesn't work, because it can't find the `.tex` file. Of course, I could just forcefully `rm` all those files, but is there a gentler way to achieve this (for instance using `latexmk` somehow)?

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Of course, I just would like to know how to remove them in case I change my document completely

Comment: looking at the latexmk manual looks like if you specify `auxdir=out` to latexmk it should handle writing aux files there and -c  would then know what to delete

Comment: It will only work if "out" is a subdirectory of the "src" directory. Any navigation to parent directories is discouraged as a safety risk.

Comment: Is it really any easier to have a `latexmk` way than just using `rm`? It isn't as though you will need to do this often, surely?